# Show that $\mathrm{Cov}[g(X), h(X)] \ge 0$ whenever $g$ and $h$ are nondecreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

Intuitively, the covariance of two nondecreasing functions of a random variable should be nonnegative. However I can't seem to come up with a proof for this.

Here is the formal setup:

Let $X: (\Omega, \mathcal A)\to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ be a random variable defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ and let $g$ and $h$ be nondecreasing functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. To make sure that everything is well-defined assume that $E[g(X)^2]<\infty$ and $E[h(X)^2]<\infty$.

**Question:** Is is always true that
$$\mathrm{Cov}[g(X),h(X)]\ge 0\,?$$

---

Some notes:

- Note that the assertion is equivalent to showing that $E[g(X)h(X)]\ge E[g(X)]E[h(X)].$
- I tried reducing the problem to showing that
  $$E[Xf(X)] \ge E[X]E[f(X)]$$
  holds for every nondecreasing $f$ whenever $E[X^2]$ and $E[f(X)^2]$ are finite. To do this, I defined $Y=h(X),$ $f = g \circ h^{-1}$ and wrote
  $$E[g(X)h(X)]=E[g(h^{-1}(Y)Y] = E[f(Y)Y].$$
  But this assumes that $h$ is strictly increasing, which is not necessarily true. Moreover, even in this case I'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Chebyshev sum inequality. The proof is also really nice. Let $X_1, X_2$ be two iid copies of $X$. Then note that
$$(g(X_1)-g(X_2))(h(X_1)-h(X_2)) \ge 0 $$
from the fact that $g,h$ are non decreasing. Taking expectations then gives us
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)h(X)] \ge \mathbb{E}[g(X)] \mathbb{E}[h(X)].$$

Comment: Thank you, this is a really elegant proof!