# When does $\mathrm{Cov}[g(X),h(X)] \ge 0$ hold for all nondecreasing $g$ and $h$ on $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question

If $X$ is a random variable then the covariance of two nondecreasing transformations of $X$ is nonnegative (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3758984/451957)). This fact is very intuitive but it turns out that it does not immediately generalize to random vectors. I am wondering what is known about the class of random vectors for which this condition holds.

To formalize this question, assume from now on the following:

- A function $g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is called *nondecreasing* if it is nondecreasing in each component.
- Let
  $$X=(X_1,\dots,X_n): (\Omega, \mathcal A) \to (\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B^n)$$
  be a random vector defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$.
- Let $g, h: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be measurable functions with $E[g(X)^2]<\infty$, $E[h(X)^2]<\infty$.

**Theorem 1:** If $g$ and $h$ are nondecreasing and $n=1$ then
$$\mathrm{Cov}[g(X),h(X)] \ge 0.$$

**Theorem 2:** If $g$ and $h$ are nondecreasing and $n\ge 2$ then $\mathrm{Cov}[g(X),h(X)] \ge 0$ does not necessarily hold.

**Question:** For $n\ge 2$, what is known about the class of random vectors $X$ for which
$$\mathrm{Cov}[g(X),h(X)] \ge 0\tag{*}$$
holds whenever $g$ and $h$ are nondecreasing?

---

Some observations:

- Note that $(*)$ is the same as
  $$E[g(X)h(X)] \ge E[g(X)]E[h(X)].$$
- If $X$ is such that $(*)$ holds for any nondecreasing $g$ and $h$ and $X$ possesses finite second moments then all components of $X$ are nonnegatively correlated. To see this, simply choose $g(x) = x_i$ and $h(x) = x_j$ for $i, j = 1,\dots, n$.
- **Theorem 3:** $(*)$ holds for any nondecreasing $g$ and $h$ if the components of $X$ are stochastically independent.

---

**Proof of Theorem 1:** See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3758984/451957).

**Proof of Theorem 2:** Let $n = 2$ and suppose $X=(X_1, X_2)$ takes on the values $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ with probability $0.5$ each. Define measurable, nondecreasing functions by $g(x_1, x_2) = x_1$ and $h(x_1, x_2) = x_2$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Cov}[g(X), h(X)] &= E[g(X)h(X)]-E[g(X)]E[h(X)]\\
                         &= E[X_1 X_2]-E[X_1]E[X_2]\\
                         &= 0-0.5\times0.5\\
                         &= -0.25.
\end{align}

**Proof of Theorem 3:** We proceed by induction on the number of components $n$. If $n=1$ we can simply apply Theorem 1. Now suppose $X$ has $n+1$ components. Write $X=(X_1, Y)$ where $Y$ consists of the last $n$ components. Then
$$E[g(X_1,Y)h(X_1,Y)|Y=y] \ge E[g(X_1,Y)|Y=y]\,E[h(X_1,Y)|Y=y]$$
since $g(\cdot,y)$ and $h(\cdot,y)$ are nondecreasing functions for any $y$. Therefore
\begin{align}
E[g(X)h(X)] &= E[\,E[g(X_1,Y)h(X_1,Y)|Y]\,] \\
            &\ge E[\,E[g(X_1,Y)|Y]\,E[h(X_1,Y)|Y]\,].
\end{align}
further, since $Y$ and $X_1$ are independent,
$$\tilde g(y) := E[g(X_1,Y)|Y=y] = E[g(X_1,y)]$$
is a nondecreasing function of the $n$-dimensional vector $y$. Hence, by applying the induction assumption,
\begin{align}
E[\,E[g(X_1,Y)|Y]\,E[h(X_1,Y)|Y]\,] &= E[\,\tilde g(Y)\,\tilde h(Y)\,]\\
                                    &\ge E[\,\tilde g(Y)]\,E[\tilde h(Y)\,] \\
                                    &= E[g(X)]\,E[h(X)].
\end{align}

It follows that $E[g(X)h(X)] \ge E[g(X)]E[h(X)].$

Comment: I guess you might be interested in the [FKG inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality), which generalizes the Harris inequality as mentioned in Theorem 1.

Comment: @SangchulLee This seems useful, thank you!