# Is $\mathbb{E}(X^{\alpha+1} \ln X) \mathbb{E}(X^\alpha) \ge \mathbb{E}(X^{\alpha+1}) \mathbb{E}(X^\alpha \ln X)$ true?

Tags: probability, inequality, convex-analysis, expected-value, jensen-inequality

Let $X$ be a random variable that is almost surely positive. Let $\alpha \ge 1$. Is it true that
$$\mathbb{E}(X^{\alpha+1} \ln X) \mathbb{E}(X^\alpha) \ge \mathbb{E}(X^{\alpha+1}) \mathbb{E}(X^\alpha \ln X)?$$

This problem arises in the following context. The following number measures the spread in the distribution of $X$:
$\frac{\mathbb{E}(X^{\alpha+1})}{\mathbb{E}(X^\alpha)}$. I would like to prove that whenever $\alpha$ increases, the measure of spread also increases.

This is true if the inequality above is true, which follows from taking first order conditions w.r.t $\alpha$, in the measure of spread.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\alpha \ge 1$, if random variable $X\ge 0$ and $0<\mathsf{E}[X^{\alpha}]<\infty$,
then the following inequality is true,
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{E}[X^{\alpha+1}\ln X]\mathsf{E}[X^{\alpha}] \ge\mathsf{E}[X^{\alpha+1}]\mathsf{E}[X^{\alpha}\ln X]. \tag{1} 
\end{equation*}
To prove (1), consider the new probability $\widetilde{\mathsf{P}} $
and expection  $\widetilde{\mathsf{E}} $ as following:
\begin{align*}
 \widetilde{\mathsf{P}}(A)&=\frac{\mathsf{E}[1_{A}X^{\alpha}]}{\mathsf{E}[X^{\alpha}]}, \\
 \widetilde{\mathsf{E}}[Y]&=\frac{\mathsf{E}[YX^{\alpha}]}{\mathsf{E}[X^{\alpha}]}. \qquad(\text{if }\mathsf{E}[|Y|X^{\alpha}]<\infty). \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Using (2), (1) is equivalent to the following inequality,
\begin{equation*}
 \widetilde{\mathsf{E}}[X\ln X] \ge \widetilde{\mathsf{E}}[X]\widetilde{\mathsf{E}}[\ln X].\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
Since $x,\ln x$ are increasing functions $\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+ $ both, from the inequality in
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758984/),
(3) holds.

Comment: Just a small detail: we should require $E[X^\alpha]>0$ too for this to work

Comment: @Snoop, Thank you, you are right. I rewrite the answer.